# $f$ such that $\frac{an}{n-b} \leq f(a,b)\cdot n $ for all $n \geq 1$

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds

I have been trying to find upper bound of following thing with no success. Is there any inequality s.t following holds .

assume that $a \geq ,b \geq 1$ then find $f(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ s.t forall $n\geq 1$

> $$\frac{an}{n-b} \leq f(a,b)\cdot n $$

Comment: Clearly not.  When $n$ gets close to $b$ the left side blows up.  Is the period supposed to be multiplication?  If so, please use \cdot to get a centered dot.  You could then divide out the $n$

Comment: @RossMillikan yup it is multiplication

Comment: Are all the numbers real or is $n$ and integer. If n is an integer and b is chosen not to be you could avoid a blowup in the lower bound in that case. Still that doesn't provide an upper bound though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $n$ is a natural number, you should divide the inequality by $n$ as @RossMillikan mentioned in the comments. Then you get $\frac{a}{n-b} \leq f(a,b)$ for all $n \geq 1$. Now it is easy to show that $\frac{a}{n-b}>\frac{a}{n+1-b}$ if $n>b$ and $\frac{a}{n-b}<0$ for all $n<b$. Thus in the case $b \notin \mathbb{N}$ the function $f(a,b)=\frac{a}{\lceil b \rceil -b}$ works, since it holds for the smallest $n>b$ and is positive. In the case $b \in \mathbb{N}$ the same argumentation holds for $f(a,b)=a$.